# GlobalFree - Incompatible types: 'NativeUInt' and 'PWideChar'

Tags: delphi, winapi

Documentation of [WinHttpGetIEProxyConfigForCurrentUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winhttp/nf-winhttp-winhttpgetieproxyconfigforcurrentuser) says:

> The caller must free the lpszProxy, lpszProxyBypass and
>   lpszAutoConfigUrl strings in the WINHTTP_CURRENT_USER_IE_PROXY_CONFIG
>   structure if they are non-NULL. Use **GlobalFree** to free the strings.

I wrote the following code (Delphi 10.3.2):

```
var
  VConfig: TWinHttpCurrentUserIEProxyConfig;
begin
  FillChar(VConfig, SizeOf(VConfig), 0);

  if not WinHttpGetIEProxyConfigForCurrentUser(VConfig) then begin
    RaiseLastOSError;
  end;
  ...

  if VConfig.lpszAutoConfigUrl <> nil then begin
    GlobalFree(VConfig.lpszAutoConfigUrl);        // <-- Error
  end;
```

and got an error:

> [dcc32 Error] E2010 Incompatible types: 'NativeUInt' and 'PWideChar'

Questions:

- should I type-cast `PWideChar` to `NativeUInt`?
- can I use `GlobafFreePtr` instead of `GlobafFree` (it accepts `PWideChar` and works fine in my tests)?

Comment: `GlobalFreePtr` calls `GlobalHandle` to get an `HGLOBAL` from a pointer, then `GlobalUnlock` to unlock that handle, then `GlobalFree`. All the examples I see online call `GlobalFree` directly on the pointer. My guess is that, these days at least, `GlobalHandle` returns its input value directly, in other words the `HGLOBAL` is the same thing as the pointer. My suggestion is that you call `GlobalFree` directly, and hence cast the pointer to `HGLOBAL`. `GlobalFree(HGLOBAL(...))`

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-globallock): *Memory objects allocated with **GMEM_FIXED** always have a lock count of zero. For these objects, the value of the returned pointer is equal to the value of the specified handle.* i.e. in some cases it's not safe to cast pointer, but `GlobalFreePtr` should be used. So, I think it would be safer to use `GlobalFreePtr` in all cases.

Comment: The excellent answer from @Anders tells you that you are wrong, and justifies why

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When MSDN tells you to free with a specific function then doing just that is your best bet.

Parts of the Windows API is written in C and (some parts even without `STRICT` defined?) and other languages with better type checking will require casts in some places.

In the case of HGLOBALs you have the `GlobalFlags` function that can help you out. In your case the low byte of flags is zero indicating that there are no locks. If the strings had been allocated as movable the documentation would have to tell you to lock before accessing the memory and it does not.

The final nail in the coffin is to debug the function and if you do that you will see that it calls `GlobalAlloc` with flags set to 0x40 (`GPTR`) and should therefore be passed to `GlobalFree` without unlocking. If your compiler complains then you must cast to the appropriate type:

```
GlobalFree(HGLOBAL(VConfig.lpszAutoConfigUrl));
```

Comment: I hope you don't mind, but I replaced the very end of your answer with Delphi specific content

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Is that even a Delphi cast? Looks like C to me. I don't remember Delphi anymore sadly.

Comment: Yup, that's the right way to do it in Delphi. `GlobalFree` is declared in `Windows.pas` to accept an `HGBLOAL`. Now, `HGLOBAL` is an alias to `THandle` which is an alias to `NativeUInt` which is where the asker gets `NativeUInt` from. However, semantically it is best to cast to `HGLOBAL` here in case anything changes in the future. Thanks for chipping in here and filling in a gap in my knowledge of winapi.